# Как правильно десериализация json файл, для вывода в консоли

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

```
   public class Track
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Driver driver { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

   public class Driver
    {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Surname { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; } 
      public int Experience { get; set; }
    }
```

Джейсон файл

```
  [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Renault Magnum",
    "Driver": {
      "Name" : "John",
      "Surname" : "Dou",
      "Age" : 35,
      "Experience" : 10
    },
    "State": "base"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Volvo FH12",
    "Driver": {
      "Name" : "Jack",
      "Surname" : "Dou",
      "Age" : 55,
      "Experience" : 30
    },
    "State": "base"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "DAF XF",
    "Driver": {
      "Name" : "Jane",
      "Surname" : "Dou",
      "Age" : 45,
      "Experience" : 15
    },
    "State": "base"
  }
]
```

При попытке десериализовать

```
Tracks = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Track[]>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Получаю только массив машин, водителей не пойму, как правильно сделать ?
Джейсон изучаю совсем недавно. Застрял на этом моменте.Пытался сделать через объект класса. Может лучше в двумерный массив, и с него сделать новые экземпляры класса?

Comment: Какой сериализатор?

Comment: System.Text.Json;

Comment: Если используете `System.Text.Json`, то запомните сразу, что она очень придирчива и пытается следовать по максимуму стандарту JSON, а это означает, что имена должны быть строго одинаковыми, лишних запятых в конце JSON быть не должно, ну и ряд других аспектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что проблема в определении класса `Track`, конкретно в этой строчке:

```
public Driver driver { get; set; }
```

В вашем JSON-файле имя свойства `Driver`, с прописной буквы, вот десериализатор и не может их сопоставить.

Исправьте указанную строчку на

```
public Driver Driver { get; set; }
```

Проверил с System.Text.Json.

Более хитрый JSON.NET умеет сопоставить свойство `driver` в C# со свойством `Driver` в JSON, но ваш код явно на System.Text.Json, т. к. десериализация строки в JSON.NET выглядела бы как

```
Tracks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Track[]>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

---

Как подсказывает @aepot в комментариях, вы можете также настроить поведение десериализатора в System.Text.Json, как [описано в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing). Например, вы можете заставить его игнорировать различие между прописными и строчными буквами так

```
Tracks = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Track[]>(
            File.ReadAllText(path),
            new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

или так:

```
Tracks = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Track[]>(
            File.ReadAllText(path),
            JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
```

Документация содержит и другие возможности по настройке, почитайте!

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Нужно прописать `JsonSerializerOptions`, чтобы игнорился регистр, по умолчанию не игнорится, либо прописать имя поля явно через аттрибут `[JsonPropertyName("driver")]`, аналог `JsonProperty` из Json.NET. Я бы добавил про это в ответ, особенно первое.

Comment: @aepot: Спасибо, хорошая идея, дописал.